# React background video doesn't play on mobile devices

Tags: html, reactjs, background, html5-video

I've been looking at many answers on how to troubleshoot html5 videos that aren't playing on a mobile device, but most are suggesting including `mute` or `playsinline`.  Currently, my background video is playing perfectly fine on a computer, but still doesn't play on any of the mobile browsers.  In fact, nothing gets loaded and only shows a blank page.

```
<div className="fullscreen-video-wrap">
  <video playsinline loop autoPlay muted autobuffer poster="./media/bg.jpg">
      <source src={require("./media/web-720cmp.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
      <source src={require("./media/web-720cmp.webm")} type="video/webm" />
      <source src={require("./media/web-720cmp.ogv")} type="video/ogg" />
      <img src={require("./media/bg.jpg")} alt=""/>
      Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  </video>            
</div>
```

Comment: Just to get it out of the way, could you check that there are no z-index, video getting out of viewport sort of issues. Maybe make a media query where the video will be 240*240.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React (HTML) video tag won't autoplay on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404642/react-html-video-tag-wont-autoplay-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem**

It looks like [muted doesn't work right when using the video tag with react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6544). The muted attribute is required for videos to autoplay on mobile.

If you inspect the html of your webpage in your browser, you should see something  like this for your video tag. Notice how there is no muted attribute. There's also no autobuffer or playsinline

```
<video loop="" autoplay="" poster="/media/bg.jpg">
    <source src="/media/web-720cmp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/media/web-720cmp.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/media/web-720cmp.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <img src="/media/bg.jpg" alt="">
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

**The Solution**

React should probably fix this, until then you can use something called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert an html block into your code. It would look like this

```
  <div className="fullscreen-video-wrap" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    <video playsinline loop autoPlay muted autobuffer poster="./media/bg.jpg">
    <source src="${require('./media/web-720cmp.mp4')}" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="${require('./media/web-720cmp.webm')}" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="${require('./media/web-720cmp.ogg')}" type="video/ogg" />
    <img src="${require('./media/bg.jpg')}" alt=""/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>            
` }}></div>
```