# React (HTML) video tag won't autoplay on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

I created a jsx variable to embed a video into my html.
Every other answer says to include

- `muted`
- `defaultMuted`, and
- `playsinline`

(which I already have).

---

The videos autoplay in safari, chrome and firefox on my computer, but not on mobile.

The start screen of the video loads, but it is paused.

Do I maybe need to do it slightly differently because I'm using React?

---

- I'm using an iPhone on iOS 13.3,
- the autoplay isn't working on safari, chrome and firefox, but only on mobile.
- The videos are all .mp4(.mov files also don't work).

```
var EmbedVideo = function(props) {
     return (
     <video webkit-playsinline playsinline autoplay="autoplay" className={props.className} muted defaultMuted loop>
            <source src={props.src} type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    )
}
```

---

**Update**

So apparently 'muted' doesn't show up when I inspect the html of my website. The node looks like this. There's a few attributes that are missing actually.

```
    <video autoplay="" class="video" loop="">
    <source src="/videos/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

[I'm reading something about the muted attributed not working with React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6544)? Someone made a [component that looks like it's the video tag, but functioning how it's supposed to](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-video-tag)(at least in my case with videos playing like gifs). I can't get it working though, it's not even autoplaying on Desktop. I'm trying just `<VideoTag src={props.src} />` because I don't know what their `poster` variable is supposed to be.

Comment: I think you should use `autoPlay`  not  `autoplay`

Comment: @bkm412 Didn't work. I tried autoplay="autoPlay", autoPlay="autoplay", and autoPlay="autoPlay". Which one did you mean?

Comment: @bkm412 which one do you mean, it's possible that I messed something else up when attempting, or there was a cache issue or something, I don't want to try all three repeatedly when I'm testing these separate issues

Comment: If I recall correctly the default behavior on mobile is to ignore autoplay in order to conserve bandwidth.

Comment: @j08691 Could you explain this more? I just got it working by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I was using gifs before, but some of the gifs were about 20 MB, and lower quality. The corresponding mp4's are about 2 MB maximum and most were about half a MB, and better quality so it just seems like a much better option. Plus isn't  the mp4 already downloaded when it's displayed with the html?(it's not an embedded youtube link)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `muted` does not work properly when using React. I had to use something called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in order for muted to show up in the component.

```
var EmbedVideo = function(props) {
   return (
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
        <video
          loop
          muted
          autoplay
          playsinline
          src="${props.src}"
          class="${props.className}"
        />,
      ` }}></div>
   )
}
```

Comment: wht does the playsinline prop do?

Comment: With "playsinline" in place, mobile browsers will play the video right where it is instead of the default, which is to open it up to fullscreen while it plays - https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/

Comment: @doublejosh What are you trying to say? With `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, the attributes for video should all be lowercase, it's `html`, not `jsx`

Comment: `muted` works if you type it as `muted="true"`. Using the string true sends the attribute to the DOM now

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and thought I'd share my solution, hoping that it helps others and saves you time and many headaches.

So, I created a component for the video and added in `autoPlay` and  `playsInline`, paying special attention to capitalization.

Here's the JSX code that I used:

```
<VideoBG 
    autoPlay={true} 
    loop={true}
    controls={false} 
    playsInline
    muted 
    src="../../videos/video4.mp4" 
    type="video/mp4" 
 />
```

Here's the styling (styled components, but basically css) that I used:

```
export const VideoBG = styled.video`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
`;
```

The `={true}` might not be necessary, but just in case, this worked for me.

Comment: can you show how you made the custom component?

Comment: I primarily used styled-components when working on this project.  To do so, you need to import styled from "styled-components" in the file where you are creating the styles for your component (basically, using JSX to style instead of CSS).  It's a lot to explain in a comment, but this tut video explains how to use react styled-components: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nl54MJDR2p8&t=1s

Answer (score 4):

### Make sure battery-saving mode is OFF

That was my problem...

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue! QA was reporting that autoplay was not working and I could make it work on my iphone. Once they disabled battery-saving it worked.

Answer (score 2):

## This solved it for me

- Use `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay` for react.
- Add `muted`

if you want to use the `autoplay` with small letters, you should assign the value `autoplay="true"`

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mahavira-uhb45) is a live code for testing

Comment: This might be new, I don't think this worked when I asked the question, so my answer might be outdated... if someone could confirm this that would be  great

Comment: @Sam, here is a demo code that shows this in action to confirm it. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mahavira-uhb45

Comment: The demo codes shows that this solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

```
<video className="landing-video" src={mp4} autoPlay="autoplay" playsInLine="playsinline" loop="true" muted="true"/>
```

I hope it helps.