# Autoplay video HTML on Safari iOS 14.2

Tags: html, ios, video, safari

I have noticed that videos that I set with an autoplay mode, don't work on Iphone iOS 14.2
Before that version everything worked fine.

Does anyone know the answer and how to fix this problem?
Maybe there's a way to autoplay video on Safari (iOS 14.2) again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`playsinline` needs to be set in addition to `muted` and `autoplay` in iOS 15.

https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/

Comment: This answer might be improved with a link to and quote from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030251).

Answer (score 7):

I have a few videos autoplaying and they are still running fine on iOS 14.2.

This is the code I'm using, as long as it it muted it should work fine.

```
<video class="video" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="">
   <source src=".mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: It is possible that the autoplay works on the iPhone 7 Plus and on an iPhone Xs Max instead not? I know it seems weird

Comment: I would think it should work the same on all iPhone, but it may be caused by the settings in accessibly for motion, which can disable autoplay.
https://www.businessinsider.com/how-do-i-turn-off-autoplay-on-the-iphone?r=US&IR=T

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but despite that option is enabled, it doesn't work on iPhone Xs Max ... very strange

Comment: @adcoding this worked for you? 
I've the same problem on iPhone 7 plus. And not just with my site but with several wondering if it's a new settings problem from the phone or am I missing something...

Comment: I'm working on MacOS 11.2.3 and autoplay does not work but autoPlay does (tested both Safari and Chrome with same effect). On IOS it does not work at all (showing the first frame of the video but not playing). I copied exactly the same code.

Comment: Update: When using React, "muted" property is not rendered. Solution for React using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418124/4214880

Answer (score 3):

The video autoplay HTML on iOS Safari 14.2 is only available for videos that have no sound or have the audio track disabled.
Try the HTML  "muted" Attribute (if you don't need the sound).

https://caniuse.com/?search=autoplay

Comment: It is possible that the autoplay works on the iPhone 7 Plus and on an iPhone Xs Max instead not? I know it seems weird

Comment: We are using an mp4 in video tags and it has no sound and uses `muted="muted"` but on iOS 15 it still refuses to play on the iPhone SE using either Safari or Chrome. This while it does play on the macOS Catalina Mac Mini desktop Safari.