How to force a animated background in a website to run on a mobile?
I'm encountering an issue with my code. I want to set a video as the background of my website. While the code runs perfectly on my computer, the video doesn't play automatically on my phone. Instead, it pauses, and I have to manually tap the screen to start the video. This problem persists even when the site is hosted on an HTTPS server. Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated—thanks in advance!


function playVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('background-video');
  if (video) {
    var playPromise = video.play();

    if (playPromise !== undefined) {
      playPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('Video is playing');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Video playback failed:', error);
      });
    }
  }
}

function redirectToMenu() {
  window.location.href = 'menu.html';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  playVideo();
  setTimeout(playVideo, 1000);
  setTimeout(redirectToMenu, 9000);
});

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playVideo();
});
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Video Background</title>
</head>

<body>

  <video id="background-video" autoplay muted playsinline>
      <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

</body>

</html>




I think you forgot to add your code to the question.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

WHat type of phone? And does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968386/autoplay-video-html-on-safari-ios-14-2#:~:text=Video%20elements%20that%20include%20%3Cvideo%20autoplay%3E%20play%20automatically,if%20the%20video%20element%20includes%20the%20muted%20attribute.

i am very sorry guys, i'm new here

i want it to work on every type of phone please

Use the muted Attribute
Many mobile browsers, including Safari and Chrome, will not autoplay videos with sound. To get around this, you should ensure that the video is muted:
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
    <source src="your-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
</video>



It will work on all type browsers ?
