# Video doesn't play on mobile - react application

Tags: reactjs, mobile, responsive-design

I have a video background for my react application.
The issue is that the video doesn't play on mobile.
This is how it looks like no matter which browser I use on mobile:

[image]

I've tried 3 options:

1)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
        <video
          loop
          muted
          autoplay
          playsinline
          src="${Video}"
        />,
      ` }}></div>
```

from here [React (HTML) video tag won't autoplay on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404642/react-html-video-tag-wont-autoplay-on-mobile-devices)

2.

```
      <video autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type='video/mp4'/>
```

3. 

Nothing worked...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you have to use the camelCase. So when you write, `autoplay`, change it to `autoPlay` and same for the `playsInLine`.

> ```
>        <video
>           loop
>           muted
>           autoPlay
>           playsInline
>           src="${Video}"
>         />
> ```

***Here is html tags explanation***

-autoPlay: play video automatically

-loop: loop the video

-className: to use it in the css

-muted: mute the video

-playsInline: for mobile. it lets the video plays in-line, not forcing the full screen video play